# Inverse selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I always lose a lot of time or this, I need quick inverse of selector in jQuery?

`Everything but $('.example');`

I even tried

`$(':not(.example)')`

Comment: And what's wrong with `$(':not(.example)')`?

Comment: @VisioN - for one thing, it's incredibly inefficient.

Comment: Don't know it's just not working..

Comment: The second one works. What do you get instead?

Comment: No sure about "quick inverse" but the selector you described should work just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 The entire idea to *"select everything but ..."* is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve because `$(':not(.example)')` is very inefficient and generally not very useful unless it's tied to some specific scope within the document (a level or a DOM sub-hierarchy).  I suspect you are asking the wrong question or trying to solve a problem the wrong way.  As always, you will get much better help if you describe the real problem rather than the solution you've dreamed up.

Comment: you might scope your search into a specific container and to only direct children, just to improve performance

Comment: @VisioN - yes "select everthing" is inefficient and generally not very practical either.  That's why I've asked the OP what their real problem is.  They are probably trying to use this to solve a problem when there is a much, much better way.

Comment: `$(':not(.example)')` Seems not to be working without specifying anything before the `:not` http://jsfiddle.net/4h2FL/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/4h2FL/

Comment: @Steve it works fine. It just changes the background of `body` as well.

Comment: @jfriend00 my problem is when oyu click enywhere but the open div, div closes..

Comment: @Arcagully - See how much better it works when you describe the real problem you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that's what you are looking for:

```
$("body").on("click", function() {
    // close div
});

$("#element").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // open div
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NamAJ/

Comment: YES, thx man :D Would vote you up, but don't have 15 rep :P

Comment: @Arcagully Now you have `;)`

Comment: Yeah, voted up, thx :D